# skimage.io.imread returns incorrect dimensions for TIFF import

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image

Importing a TIFF image using skimage.io.imread returns an array with shape (3,M,N) instead of (M,N,3).

```
In [1]: im = skimage.io.imread('image.tif')

In [2]: im.shape
Out[2]: (3, 768, 1024)

In [3]: im = skimage.io.imread('image.tif', as_grey = True)

In [4]: im.shape
Out[4]: (3, 768)

In [5]: im = skimage.io.imread('image.tif', flatten = True)

In [6]: im.shape
Out[6]: (3, 768)
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you work through it?

Comment: @Kosig I submitted this as a bug. You can follow what happened to it here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1496 Check with those guys if you think it is still a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fair to call this a bug in the flattening feature of `imread`, so it would probably be appropriate to open an issue there.

I don't think it clear which order is "correct." There's a difference of performance. If you are looping through color channels, (3, M, N) is faster. If you are looping through rows or columns, (M, N, 3) is faster. But it is clear that `flatten` and `as_grey` are failing to detect the dimensions properly.

The workaround here is obviously straightforward, but you could also look at tifffile, installable by pip or from the soft-matter conda channel like `conda install -c soft-matter tifffile`.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking tifffile is already being used as the default plugin by skimage?

Either way, calling it explicitly with imread( .... , plugin='tifffile') produces the same problems.

Comment: In this case, the conversation to gray should fail--so I think that is a legitimate bug you can report.